# Version Control: Commits vs. File Changes

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I use Tortoise SVN as my Version Control system and periodically generate a log report.

[image]

I get number of **commits analyzed** as well as number of **file changes**.

What is the difference?

Answer (score 4):

I have no idea how you're generating this report (which would be useful to add), but in SVN (and most VCS) you can commit more than one file at a time.  So, if I committed three files twice, that would be two "total commits" and six "total file changes".